# How to display the light theme in a dark theme app in Android CalendarView?

Tags: java, android, xml, styles

My android app uses `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` which gives me a no-actionbar dark theme. I would like my `CalendarView` to display as the light-theme though.. How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30975932/1761003

Answer (score 6):

You can do it this way,

```
 <CalendarView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"></CalendarView>
```